# Modifying my method as String instead of void

Tags: java, string, oop, public, void

I currently have a method called **tomorrow()** which modifies an objects attributes which in this case are day, month, year (**This ins't java.util.Date**, I've made my own Date constructor.)

So if for example I had an object called date1(30,12,2013) and I ran date1.tomorrow() it would make date1 = (1,1,2014) NOTE: We are currently assuming all months have 30 days.

Now this works fine if I keep it as public void tomorrow() and simply write

```
date1.showDate(); // show original value
date1.tomorrow(); // add 1 to day, do some if statements if day > 30, etc, etc
date1.showDate(); // show modified value
```

**BUT** I want **tomorrow()** to also have the function to print the modified date as a String, obviously I need to make my method **public String tomorrow()** and have a return section but I'm not entirely sure what I'm returning, I've tried returning showDate but it isn't working correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: This is what I currently have for my tomorrow() method

```
public void tomorrow()
{
        this.day++;
     if(this.day > 30)
        {
                this.day = 1;
                this.month++;
        }
        if(this.month > 12)
        {
                this.month = 1;
                this.year++;
        }
}
```

Comment: So you want a tomorrow method which does not modify the `Date` object?

Comment: What does `showDate` look like?

Comment: Why not return a modified Date and not modify the instance (no side effects) ? You could rename your method to `getTomorrow`

Comment: public void showDate()
        {
                System.out.print("\n\n THIS OBJECT IS STORING ");
                System.out.print(getDate());
                System.out.print("\n\n");
        }

Comment: Christophe Roussy is absolutely right - you should return a new instance of your `Date` instead of modifying `this`. As far as `print`ing, I think you want `System.out.println(""+this.month+"/"+this.day+"/"+this.year);` NOTE: I'm assuming you want it just printed on your console.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ShowDate()` must be printing only, not returning anything. So if you try to return ShowDate and your return type in `tomorrow()` is `String`, it will give you compile time error. 
So, what you can do is :

1. go in your `showDate()` method, find what it is printing, and return that same thing that `showDate()` prints in your `tomorrow()`.
2. Print the exact same thing that `showDate()` is printing , from your `tomorrow()`. In this case you don't have to modify your `tomorrow()` method to return `string`.
3. If you don't like any of the two options above and you want the values to be returned as `String` no matter what, follow the answer by PremGenError above.
4. last but not the least, I would suggest you to return the Date object itself from tomorrow, and call the showDate() on that object.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you want to print the date or return a String.
If you want to print it you can do this like this:

```
System.out.println(day + ......);
```

or, **assuming** `showDate()` prints

```
public void tomorrow()
{
     ....
     showDate();
 }
```

but if you want to return it, you can return a string, which you would get from showDate() (**assuming** its `public/private String showDate()` )

```
public String tomorrow()
{
     ....
     return showDate();
 }
```

if you don't have a method to get the date as a string, because `showDate()` yust prints it, I would recommend to implement that and call it here and in `showDate`, because if you want to change the formatting, add sth. or there is a bug in it you don't have to write/correcct it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to add a day to the current date & return it as a string form a method you can modify your method as shown below:

```
public String getTomorrow(String today) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(simpleDateFormat.parse(today));
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  // Adding one day to input date
        return simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    }
```

Please find below the sample test results for better understanding:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DateHelper {

    public String getTomorrow(String today) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(simpleDateFormat.parse(today));
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  // Adding one day to input date
        return simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        DateHelper dateHelper = new DateHelper();
        System.out.println(dateHelper.getTomorrow("28-02-2013"));
        System.out.println(dateHelper.getTomorrow("04-03-2013"));
        System.out.println(dateHelper.getTomorrow("31-03-2013"));
    }

}
```

It will produce the output:

```
01-03-2013
05-03-2013
01-04-2013
```